# boolean value resetting on next iteration of loop

Tags: c++, loops, return-value, mutators

I'm taking classes in C++, C#, and Java right now, so I think I'm getting some stuff mixed up. I'm having trouble setting an objects bool value and what's weird is that the int values I'm setting on a different objects are maintaining the change. I'm originally setting it in a function inside Main. After leaving the function and returning to the Main function, the values are correct. On the next iteration, the first object still has the new values, but the second object has reverted to the original values.

This is the loop in my Main function

```
    while (true) {

        Player player = playerQueue.front();

        //stores the current cell the player is on
        int cellNumber = gameBoard.findCell(player.getCellNum())->nodeNumber;       
        Cell currCell = gameBoard.getCellObject(cellNumber);

        //check cell property
        if (currCell.getCanBuy() == false){
            //pay the property owner
        } else {
            DisplayPlayerInfo(player, currCell);
        }
    }
```

This is where the player has an option to buy the cell. The functions for the Player object change properly, but the Cell(prop) object changes, but then reverts after the while loop iterates.

```
void DisplayPlayerInfo(Player &player, Cell &prop) {

    if (input == "y" || input == "Y") {
        if (player.getCurrency() >= prop.getPrice()) {

            //buy property
            prop.setCanBuy(false);
            player.subtractCurrency(prop.getPrice());
            player.addProperty(prop);
        }
    }
    else if (input == "n" || input == "N"){ 
        return;
    } else {
        //return error
    }
}
```

These are my setters for the Player object and Cell object respectively

```
//Player setter
void Player::setPlayerName(std::string name) { pName = name; }
void Player::setQueuePos(int q) { queuePos = q; }
void Player::setCellNum(int num) { cellNum = num; }
void Player::addCurrency(int amt) { currency += amt; }
void Player::subtractCurrency(int amt) { currency -= amt; }

//Cell setter
void Cell::setCanBuy(bool val) { canBuy = val; }
```

edit: Shortened the code to what I think is relevant to the question.

Comment: One thing I noticed while skimming through your code is this line: `Player player = playerQueue.front();` That creates a copy of the player object, which is probably not what you want. Anyways please create a [MCVE] so we can properly help.

Comment: @Max Did not know that...I thought it would just store the address of the object. Should I have made it a pointer to a Player object? Player *player = playerQueue.front();

Comment: @Neil college requirements are C, C++, and Java. My elective choices were C#, VB, Javascript, it wasn't my idea to take all of them.

Comment: Change colleges. The problem is trying to learn three languages at once, not particularly what the languages are. You are being badly taught.

Comment: @Neil I'm on my final semester, and have four weeks left. It's a bit late now. I'm transferring after I get my associates.

Comment: @NeilButterworth the problem is not three languages at once, it's three languages that can all *look similar*, where one of them that means a wildly different thing

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell currCell = `gameBoard.getCellObject(cellNumber);`
```

This is creating a new object, local to the while loop. A copy of the original object.

```
void DisplayPlayerInfo(Player &player, Cell &prop) {
```

This is passing that new object by reference into the function, which is why it maintains the altered values after leaving the function. However, these new altered values are not stored in the original object so when the loop ends, the local object is destroyed along with those altered values. Change the `gameBoard.getCellObject(cellNumber);` to return a reference instead of a copy of the original object to fix the problem. `Cell &getCellObject(int i);`

Comment: And make `currCell` a reference

Comment: @Caleth yup...gotta do that too.